# How to change line width and line color of plot_ly contour plots?

Tags: r, r-plotly

This should be very basic but I can not find how I can control the line width and color of a contour plot. Following code works for me to get a correct contour plot but the boundary lines are hard to see properly. Can you suggest something that I can add to my code for a thicker contour lines and a more prominent color?

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~c(1:50), 
y = ~seq(2, 60, 1), 
z = result, 
type = "contour", 
colorscale = 'Jet', 
autocontour = F, 
contours = list(
  start = 0,
  end = 150,
  size = 2
))
```

Answer (score 3):

It also took me (a Plotly beginner) annoyingly long to figure out. You can add a line to your code with a list of "line" parameters:

```
...
type = "contour",
line = list(width = 2, color = "red"),
...
```

You can also remove the lines with width = 0, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

move your colorscale to a position after the contour list sets the color of the line. see the code below.

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~c(1:50), 
y = ~seq(2, 60, 1), z = result, type = "contour", autocontour = F, contours = list(start = 0, end = 150,size = 2), colorscale='reds', line_width=3)
```